# Como saber se determinada coluna existe numa tabela no Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de saber se  uma coluna existe ou não no `Laravel`.

Por exemplo, quero fazer uma ordenação com dados vindos da query string. Se o valor "coluna" existir na tabela, então eu ordeno por esse campo.

```
 $coluna = Input::get('coluna');

 if (se_a_coluna_existe_na_tabela('usuarios', $coluna))
 {
     $query->orderBy($coluna);
 }
```

Comment: Voltou pro lado negro da força :( :D

Comment: Não, na verdade estou saindo do PHP aos poucos. Já baixei o Visual Studio completo e vou instalá-lo no meu PC lá em casa. :)

Comment: @bigown todos sabemos que no fim o lado negro perde :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não enquanto não for o último episódio :P

Comment: No caso, seria um parâmetro incorreto, creio que o melhor jeito é tentar ordenar, e capturar a exceção, se não houver a coluna (Caso não queira que o usuário fique sabendo que fez besteira...)

Comment: @mauhumor bem, é uma boa ideia. Também posso pegar o `QueryException` e trazer uma mensagem para o usuário

Comment: Quem deu o negativo, poderia informar o que está de errado com a pergunta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é tão dificil, você pode apenas usar o seguinte código

```
if(Schema::hasColumn('users', 'email')) ; //verifica se a tabela users tem a coluna email
{
    $query->orderBy($coluna);
}
```

pronto!

Caso tenha alguma dúvida, tente dar uma olhada na documentação do laravel.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#checking-existence

Comment: Obrigado Dênis!

Comment: De nada Wallace! Qualquer coisa é só chamar =D